# No output after running a program testing different loop structures

Tags: java, loops

This is about a program aimed to generate a series of continuous integers from 1 to 1000 which sum up to 1000. My function, While1000, works but if I try to modify this code to use other loop structures to get the same output it does not work. My modified code blocks when using do-while and for loops. I get no response when I run them in Eclipse. No syntax error or Exception warning.

Here are the different versions of the code:

```
public class While1000 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int i, j, k, sum = 0;
        for (i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
            j = i;
            sum = i;
            while (sum < 1000)
                sum += ++j;

            if (sum == 1000) {
                for (k = i; k <= j; k++)
                    System.out.print(k + " ");
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

```
public class dowhile1000 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int i, j, k, sum = 0;
        for (i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
            do {
                j = i;
                sum += ++j;
            }
            while (sum >= 1000);
            if (sum == 1000) {
                for (k = i; k <= j; k++)
                    System.out.print(k + " ");
                System.out.println();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

```
public class For1000 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int i, j, k, sum = 0;
        for (i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
            for (j = i; sum >= 1000; ++j) {
                sum += j;
            }

            if (sum != 1000) continue;
            for (k = i; k <= j; k++)
                System.out.print(k + " ");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

The right output should be:

```
28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 

55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 

198 199 200 201 202

1000
```

Comment: Are you saying the first case (class While1000) works but the other two do no?  By the way, correct indentation would help readability. This really matters!

Comment: The second case 'dowhile1000' never increments ```sum```because of the loop ```do {…} while (sum>=1000)```, so ```sum``` remains zero.  Same thing for the last case 'For1000': ```for(j=i;sum>=1000;++j)```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are a bit sloppy with brackets and indentation. That does not improve the readability of your code.

dowhile1000: the do-while-loop and the while loop would be different, if the while condition could be false before entering the loop. That is not the case. So the do-while-condition has to be the same than the while condition. Your do-while condition is not true after the first run of the loop, so the loop terminates. And of course j and sum have to be intitialized before the while loop. j is reset with every loop run in your code.

For1000: A for loop is repeated as long as the condition in statement 2 is true. In the for-j-loop, the condition is never true when entering the loop, so the loop is never executed. sum has to be reset before every new j. Because j is incremented after the for condition is true, in the for-k-loop the test has to be k

```
public class While1000 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

    int i, j, k, sum = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {

        j = i;
        sum = i;

        while (sum < 1000)
        sum += ++j;

        if (sum == 1000) {
        for (k = i; k <= j; k++)
            System.out.print(k + " ");
        System.out.println();
        }
    }
    }
}

public class Dowhile1000 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

    int i, j, k, sum = 0;
    for (i = 999; i <= 1000; i++) {

        j = i;
        sum = 0;

        do {
        sum += j++;
        } while (sum < 1000);

        if (sum == 1000) {
        for (k = i; k < j; k++)
            System.out.print(k + " ");
        System.out.println();
        }

    }
    }
}

public class For1000 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

    int i, j, k, sum = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
        sum = 0;
        for (j = i; sum < 1000; ++j) {
        sum += j;
        }

        if (sum != 1000)
        continue;
        for (k = i; k < j; k++)
        System.out.print(k + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. When you are in a loop you have to re-initialization your variable
2. The stop condition are important

**dowhile1000**

```
for (i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
    --> j = i;   // Shouldn't be initialization do-while
    --> sum = 0; // Should be initialization to 0 after each iteration
    do {
        sum += ++j;
    }
    --> while (sum < 1000); // Keep adding to the sum until is greater than 999
    if (sum == 1000) {
        for (k = i + 1; k <= j; k++)
            System.out.print(k + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

**For1000**

```
for (i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
    --> sum = 0; // Should be initialization to 0 after each iteration
    --> for (j = i; sum < 1000; ++j) { // Keep adding to the sum until is greater than 999
        sum += j;
    }

    if (sum != 1000) continue;
    for (k = i; k < j; k++)
        System.out.print(k + " ");
    System.out.println();
}
```